# How can I query that which student is registered in which course? Also which Teacher is teaching which courses

Tags: django, list

Here are my models.
This is my model and I want to query which students are registered in which courses and which teacher is teaching them.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

from django.utils import timezone

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_name


class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rollnum = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" (self.student_name,self.rollnum)


class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" (self.course_name,self.course_code)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    is_present = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Also kindly tell me is this approach right?

Comment: Teacher has no relationship with anything else.

Comment: How can I add Relationship? Should I use foreign key? I mean can you explain by giving an example?

Comment: Or should I make a new table in which both the students and teacher have foreign keys and from there I can write query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relationships between your tables. I suggest you add :

- [A Many To Many Relatitionship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) between Course and Student : because a student can have many courses and a courses can have many students registered.

  ```
  class Student(models.Model):
      student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      rollnum = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
      courses = models.ManyToMAnyField(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      def __str__(self):
          return "%s, %s" (self.student_name,self.rollnum)
  ```

  And the query to have the student's (I'll name his instance s1) courses is :

  ```
  s1_courses=s1.courses.all()
  ```

  And the query to have a course's (let's call it c1) registered students is :

  ```
  c1_students = c1.student_set.all()
  ```
- [A Many To One Relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) between Teacher and Course : because a teacher can teach many courses and a course can be taught only by one teacher.

  ```
  class Course(models.Model):
  course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  course_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  def __str__(self):
      return "%s, %s" (self.course_name,self.course_code)
  ```

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving an error in many to many field.

Comment: super(ManyToManyField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Comment: I have a project to complete and I am new to this. Can you help me? By giving me your number or email id? I may need to ask lot more questions.